# optimize subscribe angular to get data from api

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Hello i have a method in my api that returns Ienumerable and it is working fast but i still wait munch time to get the response from server in my method typescript.I didn't understand how to optimize it and why it takes munch time.

Here my method in ts that takes munch time to receive results :

```js
  GetList() {
    this.busy = this.service.Getlist(this.id).subscribe(
      results => {
        this.List = results;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.List);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    )
  }
```

Here my method in service angular and it is fast no problem with it :

```js
  Getlist(id:any){
    return this._http.get(this.root + 'users/Getusersbyid/'+ id);
  }
```

Here my method in api and it is fast :

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("Getusersbyid/{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<user> Getusers(decimal id)
    {
        var users= _userService.Getusers(id);
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: The problem might be you're using __MatTable__, which seems to be slow. An easy way to solve performance problems with third party components such as MatTable is that you implement pagination so you don't have huge number of data.

Comment: is this really using pagination ? or are you are getting the whole list of users? if yes, try to use the async pipe in your HTML just pass to your mat table a dataSource with an async pipe something like this <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"> ...

Comment: i'm getting the whole list with 600 rows and i'm using pagination in the template

Comment: @mecabmecab95 ah pagination should happen in the backend first dont get the whole 600 rows, get only the number of users you want to display in the first page for example 10

Comment: @Amine i'm trying to avoid pagination in backend but it is a nice solution

Comment: @mecabmecab95 ideally pagination starts in backend by selecting a page of certain size. anyway I'm almost certain this is the reason for the long loading time

Comment: i have displayed only 5 items and i have the same problem you see it is not from pagination

Comment: Try to put all your code outside the observable and in the observable put `this.dataSource = this.list`

Comment: and for this code this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.list ); what i do

Comment: Try `this.dataSource.data = results;` instead of `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.List);`

Comment: @igor_c  Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

Comment: @mecabmecab95 you should also add `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);` where you declare your properties